# Collection was of a fixes size - IronPython

Tags: python, .net, python-2.7, treeview, ironpython

I have a list of tuples as follows. I want to display it in a tree view as a hierarchy according to the numbers in middle. For example, 1 should contain 2 and 2 should contain 3 and so on.

```
(u'100K_063.txt', 1, u'Entertainment')
(u'100K_078.txt', 2, u'Health')
(u'100K_065.txt', 3, u'Entertainment')
(u'100K_064.txt', 4, u'Entertainment')
(u'100K_219.txt', 5, u'Religion')
(u'100K_220.txt', 6, u'Religion')
(u'100K_221.txt', 6, u'Religion')
(u'100K_079.txt', 4, u'Health')
(u'100K_077.txt', 4, u'Health')
```

I am trying to use the following IronPython code to form a tree hierarchy, but adding new nodes throws an exception saying the collection was of fixed size.

```
    self._treeView1.Nodes.Add("0","Nodes")

    for tuple in cluster_list:
        node = self._treeView1.Nodes.Find(str(tuple[1]),True)
        if node is not None:
            node.Add(str(tuple[0]) + " " + str(tuple[2]))
        else:
            self._treeView1.Nodes.Add(str(tuple[1]),"Level " + str(tuple[1]))
```

Comment: Please show the actual error and traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how can I get that?

Comment: Presumably it's displayed wherever you ran the code.